# How to get class / interface type clone with 'forgotten' property types ('any' instead of 'string' | 'boolean' etc.)?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

how to get class / interface type clone with 'forgotten' property types ('any' instead of 'string' | 'boolean' etc.)? Please consider the following code:

```js
class Pet {
  name: string;
}

class User {
  username: string;
  pet: Pet;
}

type MakePropTypesAny<T> = T; // what here?

const q: MakePropTypesAny<User> = {
  username: true, // error: 'boolean' != 'string --> I want 'any' here
  pet: {
    name: true, // error: 'boolean' != 'string' --> I want 'any' here
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `MakePropTypesAny<T>` to be a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which turns `T` into `any` if `T` is not an object, and otherwise it produces a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which walks down into each property at key `K` of `T` and recursively applies `MakePropTypeAny` to each one:

```
type MakePropTypesAny<T> =
  T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: MakePropTypesAny<T[K]>
  } : any;
```

This turns `User` into the type you're looking for:

```
type AnyUser = MakePropTypesAny<User>;
/* type AnyUser = {
    username: any;
    pet: {
        name: any;
    };
} */
```

And your example works as desired:

```
const q: MakePropTypesAny<User> = {
  username: true,
  pet: {
    name: true,
  },
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEAFApgF3gb1PeA7KAtsgIQBc8MqATgJa4DmA3KAL6iiSwICqMyVmbPACufKviJkK1OkyEAHNFJSpmINiFCoAnovgBZKAGtkiKgHt5AFV3IYAQVzaAPFYB88ALxCr8ZAA9UZFwAEwRzACMAK2QwdAB+QRAcHABtAGl4OngTbXMAM3grAF1yQxMzSxtFBydXDOK3IRZ4cignNS1beEdtXn4vA2NTC2tbWpd+qjc1AHoAKngdPV6pwaxklNF+CWQ2jqEcRVRyDZTzvEI9+HbtNXOWNRb52fZwc1xKeABHMuHKsY1XrOKYeTxJHDbcRXcjUYTIAA0CjQp0OlyIsKo8KRmxYOMebyAA)