# How to pick nested fields from an interface / class?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'd like to get a specific type returned from `fn` function. Please consider the following code:

for more context; this is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110721/how-to-get-class-interface-type-clone-with-forgotten-property-types-any-i)

```js
class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class Book {
  title: string;
  author: Person;
}

type MakePropTypesAny<T> = T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]: MakePropTypesAny<Partial<T[K]>>;
    }
  : any;

type ClassConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type ParseReturnType<T> = T; // < - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - what here?

const fn = <T>(
  obj: ClassConstructor<T>,
  fields: Partial<MakePropTypesAny<T>>
): ParseReturnType<T> => {
  return {} as any;
};

const res = fn(Book, { author: { firstName: true } });
```

`res` has `Book` type, but I'd like it to have the following type:

```js
type ToBeReturned = {
  author: {
    firstName: string; // because Person.firstName is 'string'
  };
};
```

as you can see the above type is the passed `fields` argument, but with field-types from `Book` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `ParseReturnType` similar to how you defined `MakePropTypesAny`, but with `fields` and `obj` as input. You recursively map through the object structure of `fields` and apply the keys of `fields` to `obj` at the same time with [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-xUARkmlDQpGwCCoK-YFlF4BDoGlLYkkQBJoAAciwgDiPNFBCmgNAUB1ZphSIKsb2IY0IAAJlqDg0GfCxLDfD9oO-LAlEgbC1ApMh4FkODxMAqSQOgMDUMKdjIM-GDZIA3D0WQyQVI49ShMwsTtKQ3wUKAA)):

```
class Person {
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string){}
}

class Book {
  constructor(public title: string, public author: Person){}
}

type MakePropTypesAny<T> = T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]?: MakePropTypesAny<T[K]>;
    }
  : true;

type ClassConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

// Recursively map through U and T until a primitive type is found.
// Then return the type of T at the current recursion depth.
type ParseReturnType<T, U> = U extends object ? {
  [K in keyof U]: ParseReturnType<T[Extract<K, keyof T>], U[K]>
}: T; 


function fn<T, U extends MakePropTypesAny<T>>(
  obj: ClassConstructor<T>,
  fields: U
): ParseReturnType<T, U> {
  return {} as any;
};

const res = fn(Book, { author: { firstName: true } } );
res.author.firstName // string
res.author.lastName // Property 'lastName' does not exist

const res2 = fn(Book, { author: { lastName: true, firstName: true} } );
res2.author.firstName // string
res2.author.lastName // string
```

For the `ParseReturnType`, it is necessary to use `T[Extract<K, keyof T>]` instead of `T[K]`, because typescript doesn't know that `keyof U` is a subset of `keyof T`. If we just used `T[K]`, the compiler would complain with *"Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'"*. [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) is a utility type that is defined as `Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never`. We can use that to make the compiler believe that `Extract<K, keyof T>` can only be a subset of `keyof T`, even though it doesn't do anything in reality.